# Combining countries in a region and displaying it on the same column

Tags: sql, union

Is there a way to combine countries into groups and displaying them in the same output column? I don't want to manipulate the raw database.

E.g.

- Austria          10
- Belgium          30
- Switzerland      25

Now AT, BE, CH are group-1 countries, and in my output I want to display as below:

- Austria          10
- Belgium          30
- Switzerland      25
- Group-1          65

Answer (score 0):

```
select country_name, val
from country_table
union all
select 'Group-1' as country_name, sum(val) as val
from country_table
```

You should add grouping and union both queries.